# Fast inplace matrix transpose library

Tags: library, c++, matrix

I am looking for a library routine callable from C++ to do an **inplace matrix transpose**. And I would like it done fast. Arbitrary size 2d dense matrices need to be supported.

By in-place, I mean not much extra storage should be allocated. Using a full size temporary does not count.

Eigen's has an [transposeInPlace](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac501bd942994af7a95d95bee7a16ad2a) only has the effect of an in-place transpose. It still uses a full copy's worth of memory (when not square).

MKL's `imatcopy` does work inplace but it does so very slowly. On about 1GB input: `omatcopy`, 00.2s; `imatcopy`, 32.5s.

I've seen a few academic papers but I've not found usable code.

A permissive licences is preferred, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

In-place transpose for a rectangular m x n matrix in C++.

```
#include <algorithm>
    
template<typename T>
    inline void transpose(T* A, long m, long n)
    {
        if (m<n) std::swap(m, n);
        
        while (m > 1 && n > 1)
        {
            for (long i = 1; i < m; i++)
                std::rotate(A+i, A+i*n, A+i*n+1);
            
            A += m;
            n -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Based on the ideas laid out [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/112076/in-place-matrix-transposition-using-rotations). Probably a much faster way would be using FFTW, as described [here](https://agentzlerich.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-fftw-for-in-place-matrix.html).